# Error 1310. Error writing to file: C:\Config.Msi\997da2c.rbf

Tags: installation, installshield, uninstallation

I am facing a peculiar problem; I am creating a `setup.exe` in Installshield 2008 Primer Edition and install the setup in a laptop which has the Operating System Windows XP Professional.

The setup runs fine and install all the files successfully but when I click the Uninstall icon during Uninstallation process the below error will appear

> Product: [Product Name] -- Error 1310. Error writing to file:
>   C:\Config.Msi\997da2c.rbf. system error 5. verify that you have access
>   to that directory.

Though I have surfed and got couple of answers like Unregister the msi engine and again register it that is:

```
msiexec /unreg
msiexec /regserver
```

By unregistering and reregistering the server will solve the right now; but after a couple of days the popup starts appearing again.

[Some](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/408/kb408730.html) [sites](http://windowstipsandfixes.blogspot.com/2008/10/error-1310-cant-write-to-configmsi.html) say the problem is that proper access rights are not given; I have cross-verified in the laptop also the user is having full control to the `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users` folder.

One more point I need to make: I am unable to simulate the above problem for desktop systems. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: The message doesn't complain about access to C:\Documents and Settings\All Users. The message says "C:\Config.Msi\" check if you have acces to that folder. Did you try all the advices on the pages you link too?

Comment: Yes you are correct the message will come as no access for "C:\Config.Msi\"; i am giving full access to C:\Documents and Settings\All Users.
I tried one of the option by Un registering and reregistering the Msiexec engine. then i run the Uninstallation process it works fine..
But the client will not accpet; when ever this problem occurs every time approaching the same process..

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the installer and choose "Run as Administrator"

Answer (score 0):

I have faced error 1310 and I think error 1310 is one of the common error.

1. Click Start.
2. Click the arrow button next to the Shutdown option.
3. Select Log-Off option.
4. Wait till the active user account is logged-off.
5. Select the administrator user account, enter valid password and log-in to your computer.
6. Re-start the installation program.